# Data type issue renders value to not be "assignable." Possible pointer issue?

Tags: c, pointers, types, variable-assignment

I can't waste another day on this confounded error.  Can you please help?  Here is the code.  Some details might be astray, however, I cant compile until this error is resolved.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string note = argv[1];

    int frequency(string note);
    int duration(string fraction);

    if (argc == 2)
    {
       // create new string with last 3 chars in string note

        string fraction = note + strlen(note) - 3;
        printf("(%.3s)\n", fraction);

        // transform char into integer.. poof!

        int x = atoi(&fraction[0]);
        int y = atoi(&fraction[-1]);

       // calculate integer from x & y values

        duration = x * (8 / y);
        printf("%i\n", duration);


    }
    else
    {
        printf("Two (2) arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }


}
```

AND THE ERROR MESSAGEs..

```
duration.c:61:18: error: non-object type 'int (string)' (aka 'int (char *)') is not assignable
        duration = x * (8 / y);

        ~~~~~~~~ ^
duration.c:62:24: error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int (*)(string)' (aka 'int (*)(char *)') [-Werror,-Wformat]
        printf("%i\n", duration);
```

Comment: `duration` is a function and cannot be assigned a value. Why would you even try to do that?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is `duration` even a function?  It looks like it was given a prototype as if it were a function... inside main.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons A wannabe function :)

Comment: FYI, `&fraction[0]` is the same as just `fraction`. And `&fraction[-1]` is `fraction-1`

Comment: What is this program supposed to do? Your `x` and `y` assignments seem suspicious to me.

Comment: @ Eugene.  I would "try to do that" in order to solve a problem.  Furthermore, I am assigning a formula to duration not a value.  Unfortunately your comment is not very helpful.

Comment: You assign a formula to a function name by writing a function definition, not an assignment.

Comment: Like `function add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `duration` to be a *function* that takes a `string` (`char *`) argument and returns an `int`:

```
int duration(string fraction);
```

Function expressions are indeed not assignable - a function cannot be the target of the `=` operator, hence the error on

```
duration = x * (8 / y);
```

If you want `duration` to simply be an integer variable, declare it as

```
int duration;
```

<gratuitous rant>

The `string` typedef in the `cs50.h` header is a *mistake*, and it *will* lead you astray when thinking about string operations in C.  It makes string operations in C look more high-level than they really are.

A *string* in C is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are stored in arrays of `char`.  Under most circumstances, an expression of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", so when we're dealing with strings we're usually dealing with *expressions* of type `char *`, but a `char *` is *not a string*.  A `char *` *may* point to the first character in a string, or it may point to the first character in a sequence that isn't a string, or it may point to a single character that isn't part of a larger sequence.

C string operations are *extremely* low level.  The `string` typedef is obviously an attempt to abstract away some of that, but it's a weak, leaky abstraction at best, and an active hinderance to learning proper string processing techniques in C at worst.  Be *really* careful when using it.

</gratuitous rant>

**EDIT**

Then it looks like what you want to do is something like this:

```
/**
 * Define the duration function to compute x * 8/y
 */
int duration( char *frac )
{
  int x = atoi( frac );
  int y = atoi( frac - 1 );

  return x * (8 / y);
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  // yadda yadda yadda

    char *fraction = note + strlen(note) - 3;
    printf("(%.3s)\n", fraction);

    printf("%i\n", duration( fraction ) ); // call duration with
                                           // fraction as an argument
  // yadda yadda yadda
}
```

Comment: Actually, I do want duration to be a function.  I guess I just don't understand the appropriate syntax.  if I replaced "duration," with "return," ??                                                     return  x * (8 / y)

Comment: Thanks John Bode!  I was able to work this out with your help.  Best L_L